# How to tell if a menu link is route:<nolink> or not?

Tags: 8, theming, navigation

Trying to theme a menu in Drupal 8, running into a case where we need to add classes on certain links.

In the case of a menu link that is `route:<nolink>` we need to not add any class at all.

Example:

```
{% if item.below and item.url %}
 {{ link(item.title, item.url, { 'class':['link', 'link--arrow']} ) }}
{% else %}
 // not a link
{% endif %}
```

How can we tell at this level that `item.url` is `route:<nolink>`?

Update:

Current solution so far, is there a better way?

```
{% if not item.url.isExternal() and item.url.getRouteName() is same as('<nolink>') %}
  {{ link(item.title, item.url) }}
{% else %}
  {{ link(item.title, item.url, { 'class':['link', 'link--arrow']} ) }}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be able to do a toString and if it's not actually a link that will come back empty

```
{% if item.below and item.url and item.url.toString|length > 0 %}
```

Comment: We tried length, but without the toString part.

Comment: I think item.url|length would always be greater than 0 even for nolinks as its an array of renderable stuff I think. I've just tried the toString idea and seems to work

Answer (score 0):

Or try this:

```
{% if item.below and item.url and item.url.getRouteName() != "<nolink>" %}
```